# How would I go about fixing my variable rate SDL timestep?

Tags: c++, game-loop, sdl2

I my gameloop is going around 10x faster than what it should be and I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried multiple different other variable rate timesteps but none seem to be as effective as this one.

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    Uint32 t = 0;
    Uint32 dt = 10000 / 60.0;

    Uint32 currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();

    game = new Renderer();

    game->init("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

    while(game->running()){
        
        Uint32 newTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        Uint32 frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
        currentTime = newTime;

        while(frameTime > 0.0)
        {
            float deltaTime = std::min(frameTime, dt);
            game->handleEvents();
            game->update(deltaTime/1000);
            frameTime -= deltaTime;
            t += deltaTime;
            
            t += dt;
        }
        game->render();
    }

    game->clean();

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I call

```
g.transform.position.x+=1/60.0;
```

in the render function, I expect it to move 1 pixel every 1 second but it moves way to fast.
Does anyone know how I can slow this down or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Uint32 dt = 10000 / 60.0;  
This should mean 1000 / 60.0, right if this is original source, your item moves 10times faster than 60 fps

Comment: I tried that and it just makes it faster. The original from gaffer on games is in seconds while this one is in milliseconds.

Comment: yeah but milliseconds are 1000 / 60.0 = 16.666 ms per frame, not 166.66 ms per frame. 
There is another error but twisting numbers until it works is not the right strategy :)

Comment: The other problem is that you always call the update as long as frameTime >0.0 so if frameTime is always 1 ms, you will still run the while loop 1000 times per second. As you call game->update(...) it seems you are not taking this time argument into account in your update function (at least in your sniplet)

Comment: If there were 3.5/60 of a second since the last render, your game loop runs 1/60 and then 1/60 and then 1/60 and then another 0.5/60 so 4 steps in 3.5/60 of a second. If there was 0.001/60 of a second your game loop runs 1 step with 0.001/60 of a second. This is not a fixed timestep loop.